# How to recreate composite index with the help 'all_ind_columns'

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a `table(XXX)` which has composite indexing on two of the `columns(A,B)`. I am extracting those indexes into another table by using query:

```
create table YYY as
    select index_name, table_name, column_name
    from all_ind_columns
    where table_name = 'XXX';
```

I get two rows for table XXX, each row representing different `columns(A,B)` but same `index_name(INDEX1)`.

How shall I recreate them in the same manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following query to generate the "create index" statement:

```
 select 
   'create index '
 || index_name 
 ||'  on YYY (' 
 || listagg( column_name, ',') within group (order by column_position) 
 || ');'  
from all_ind_columns where table_name='XXX' group by index_name;
```